# python logistic regression (beginner)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, patsy

I'm working on teaching myself a bit of logistic regression using python. I'm trying to apply the lessons in the walkthrough [here](https://github.com/justmarkham/gadsdc1/blob/master/logistic_assignment/kevin_logistic_sklearn.ipynb) to the small dataset in the wikipedia entry[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

Something doesn't seem quite right. Wikipedia and Excel Solver (verified using the method in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbKtZcrTlr8)) give intercept -4.0777 and coefficient 1.5046, but the code I built out from the github example outputs -0.924200 and 0.756024, respectively.

The code I'm attempting to use is below. Any glaring mistakes?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


X = [0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.5,1.75,1.75,2.0,2.25,2.5,2.75,3.0,3.25,
3.5,4.0,4.25,4.5,4.75,5.0,5.5]
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]

zipped = list(zip(X,y))
df = pd.DataFrame(zipped,columns = ['study_hrs','p_or_f'])

y, X = dmatrices('p_or_f ~ study_hrs',
                  df, return_type="dataframe")

y = np.ravel(y)

model = LogisticRegression()
model = model.fit(X,y)
print(pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(model.coef_),X.columns))

>>>
                  0
Intercept -0.924200
study_hrs  0.756024
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Solution

Just change the model creation line to

```
model = LogisticRegression(C=100000, fit_intercept=False)
```

### Analysis of the problem

By default, sklearn solves **regularized LogisticRegression**, with fitting strength `C=1` (small C-big regularization, big C-small regularization).

> This class implements regularized logistic regression using the
>   liblinear library, newton-cg and lbfgs solvers. It can handle both
>   dense and sparse input. Use C-ordered arrays or CSR matrices
>   containing 64-bit floats for optimal performance; any other input
>   format will be converted (and copied).

Thus to obtain their model you should fit

```
model = LogisticRegression(C=1000000)
```

which gives

```
Intercept -2.038853 # this is actually half the intercept
study_hrs  1.504643 # this is correct
```

Furthermore the problem also lies in the way you work with data in patsy, see the simplified, correct example

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = [0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.5,1.75,1.75,2.0,2.25,2.5,2.75,3.0,3.25,
3.5,4.0,4.25,4.5,4.75,5.0,5.5]
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]

X = np.array([[x] for x in X])
y = np.ravel(y)

model = LogisticRegression(C=1000000.)
model = model.fit(X,y)

print('coef', model.coef_)
print('intercept', model.intercept_)
```

gives

```
coef [[ 1.50464059]]
intercept [-4.07769916]
```

What is the problem exactly? When you do `dmatrices` it by default embeds your input data with a column of ones (biases)

```
X = [0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.5,1.75,1.75,2.0,2.25,2.5,2.75,3.0,3.25,
3.5,4.0,4.25,4.5,4.75,5.0,5.5]
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]

zipped = list(zip(X,y))
df = pd.DataFrame(zipped,columns = ['study_hrs','p_or_f'])

y, X = dmatrices('p_or_f ~ study_hrs',
                  df, return_type="dataframe")

print(X)
```

which leads to

```
    Intercept  study_hrs
0           1       0.50
1           1       0.75
2           1       1.00
3           1       1.25
4           1       1.50
5           1       1.75
6           1       1.75
7           1       2.00
8           1       2.25
9           1       2.50
10          1       2.75
11          1       3.00
12          1       3.25
13          1       3.50
14          1       4.00
15          1       4.25
16          1       4.50
17          1       4.75
18          1       5.00
19          1       5.50
```

and this is why the resulting bias is just **a half** of the true one - scikit learns also added a column of ones... so you now have **two biases**, thus optimal solution is to give each of them half of the weight which would be given to a single one.

So what you can do?

- do not use patsy in such a way
- forbid patsy to add a bias
- tell sklearn not to add bias

.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X = [0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.5,1.75,1.75,2.0,2.25,2.5,2.75,3.0,3.25,
3.5,4.0,4.25,4.5,4.75,5.0,5.5]
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]

zipped = list(zip(X,y))
df = pd.DataFrame(zipped,columns = ['study_hrs','p_or_f'])

y, X = dmatrices('p_or_f ~ study_hrs',
                  df, return_type="dataframe")

y = np.ravel(y)

model = LogisticRegression(C=100000, fit_intercept=False)
model = model.fit(X,y)
print(pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(model.coef_),X.columns))
```

gives

```
Intercept -4.077571
study_hrs  1.504597
```

as desired

Comment: Note to self: don't use patsy